# Typescript : how to make type system accurately determine output type based on inputs using <generics>

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Having a problem with the type system not accurately determining the output type based on the inputs.

**Types Used:**

```
type inputs = "alpha" | "beta" | "gamma";

type AlphaSchema = {
    pet: string,
    house: string
}

type BetaSchema = {
    boss: string,
    work: string,
}

type GammaSchema = {
    monk: string,
    temple: string,
}

type Schemas = {
    'alpha': AlphaSchema,
    'beta': BetaSchema,
    'gamma': GammaSchema 
}

type BuilderStore = {
    buildersFor: {
        [key in inputs] : {
            build: (str1: string, str2: string) => Schemas[key]
        }
    };
}
```

**Working Example:**

```
const exampleSchemaResults = {
    'alpha' : {pet: 'scooby', house: 'West Garden Home'},
    'beta' : {boss: 'Jake', work: 'The Royal Palace'},
    'gamma' : {monk: 'Tai', temple: 'Shaolin'},
}

const getExampleSchema: <T extends inputs>(input: T) => Schemas[T] = (input) => exampleSchemaResults[input];

const alphaExample = getExampleSchema('alpha');
```

In this case typescript is able to accurately determine that the obtained result will be of type ***AplhaSchema***

**Example that does not resolve:**

```
const store: BuilderStore = {
    buildersFor : {
        'alpha': {
            build: (str1: string, str2: string): AlphaSchema => { return {pet: str1, house: str2} },
        },
        'beta': {
            build: (str1: string, str2: string): BetaSchema => { return {boss: str1, work: str2} },
        },
        'gamma': { 
            build: (str1: string, str2: string): GammaSchema => { return {monk: str1, temple: str2} }
        }
    }
}

const getBuilder = <T extends inputs>(input : T) => store.buildersFor[input];

const build = <T extends inputs>(input: T, str1: string, str2: string) => getBuilder(input).build(str1, str2);

const schema = build('alpha', 'scooby', 'West Garden Home');
```

Issue here is that the final schema obtained is of type :

***AlphaSchema | BetaSchema | GammaSchema***

I want it to be type :

***AlphaSchema***

I understand this code generates the schema using the build function, but shouldn't this resolve similar to the working snippet mentioned above ?

Can we not resolve output schema based of the inputs (given that 'alpha' is used in the generic) ? Or is this not possible ?

Is there something wrong in the way the functions are typed ?

[TS playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAlgdmArsAzlAvFARAQwDZgAWOWUAPtgEYTAnnYDmOAtsyQNwBQnokUAggWIBlAMaEIbDFADenKAqiRgALigpgAJ3gMANPMWEA9ohQQ1G7XAacAvt17QAQjRxiJUzHMVRKRlCgWWjr6PgDuRpoA1kFWenYO4NAA4ixs7pI40t6KzEZwMerB1qGKwJJgeOZFcfr2PElQGWxoXgYKAOT4RDgdaoI9zTilndS0fVAutEMjUB1MrL1qqYtDUAkNfE6IMHgAJhCawsCR0G0+lDv7hygAYpFqOT4KANpRECCwcF9IqAC6UEe7WeFyuezUAApLABGWIhGoAJjh1gAlBgAHxNcSZFBvD5-YE+exErj1AD0ZKaMGYlWgEAAHixaVAwhJNNAACoATQACgBRWBoA7lTTMeAQPZQHCiUSITQ4cp4EDcUT5DRQBlMqpDABKEBQiDwqGywK6Ql6gNkyjUHRQqqMlBAHV0UGMpmqHQA6vrgFBUpoDt8ABJGZgQDq2WYdMYWx5+AI2gBSOHezpZkUKHQ5EigOqMIHwUB5+Gl4cjpoWbA6lpkeQKNo5OBgafKNKqNuExCMeHgEbqKrVvoYND5jLbECGagAPByNfTynA9mh4L8UOiISvkGoOWj0JihriOQDMBuEMhd5jNePdfrDagXpvgH8uJxVXB1d1iKOtWcoMPgN+17YmwEJmj0HQoi+FJQIBzKIIuhxQAAjogPowPkA7vr6GinGo2y7AcRwnOyJqggRNz3JoNaEooYHEBMTwgoolwEZCMLInoiIcSi-Tmmse6yFA7LAHK3wyNaNTQi6bpmLECK2FA5ZMYpsw+NGrgMTRIIsfsbFaLCNTwpYSKGaieGuPxmIyEJNCibI8aBJJLoRNEckKUpTEeSC8xpEsglac8OnglAUL6RxLrGdxyy+ZZgnCXZtb5IUMIuq2tJuYpAXEoo9j1G+6r-vh1xUZgM5zguS4-Mga6nr8lo7hiRSnAAdEFFGRA+Z5Pi++W+kF0hlQyFXLl1NWPtuEVhaZnGRdNF5-jQRWEbV56tWCoWaFJiKQZh6p2h4WSYEFoGfr0Lq2vajppl6Pp+jgAYQMGobhjtnDQZ6hCfHsRj6uowFZA6ABWECiL6bLQMQABu0DADmjgCHx-30FMbhIxQKzpP93DQQAwjg3wwL6cBGL68AAGaIYTUAnL40ADCISMAPy+DgZiSvk1M5o+SiaEYkMwAckqM4zQA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting behavior. I also would have expected that to work. To me it seems that when TS is statically creating the "type" of `getBuilder(input).build` it doesn't know which builder function is going to be called. If you add an explicit return type to the `build` function you can see the error more clearly.

```
const build = <T extends inputs>(input: T, str1: string, str2: string): Schemas[T] => getBuilder(input).build(str1, str2);
```

[image: TS error]

This seems to confirm that TS isn't aware of which `build` function is going to be called, so the return type is all of them.
To fix it, you can cast the return type to the correct Schema:

```
const build = <T extends inputs>(input: T, str1: string, str2: string): Schemas[T] => (getBuilder(input).build(str1, str2) as Schemas[T]);
```

This removes all errors and gives that final `schema` variable the right type.